# Как получить значения из множества input на странице средствами javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var voprosy = [{
    "vopros": 'Столица Туркменистана?',
    "otvety": [
      'Ащхабад',
      'Мары',
      'Дашогуз',
    ],
    "otvet": [0]
  },
  {
    "vopros": 'Столица Италии?',
    "otvety": [
      'Милан',
      'Ватикан',
      'Рим',
    ],
    "otvet": [3]
  },
  {
    "vopros": 'Столица России?',
    "otvety": [
      'Москва',
      'Санкт-Петербург',
      'Тула',
    ],
    "otvet": [0]
  }
];

window.onload = draw();

function draw() {
  var questionBlock = '';
  var vopr = document.querySelector('.vopr');
  for (var i = 0; i < voprosy.length; i++) {
    var qwest = voprosy[i].vopros;
    questionBlock += '<div class="col-md-6 text-center"><h3>';
    questionBlock += qwest;
    questionBlock += '</h3>';

    for (var j = 0; j < voprosy[i].otvety.length; j++) {
      questionBlock += '<input type="radio" name ="answer_' + i + '" value="' + j + '" />' + voprosy[i].otvety[j] + '<br />';
    }

    questionBlock += '</div>';

  }
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questionBlock;
}

function ok() {
  if (answer_0 == 0 && answer_1 == 2 && answer_2 == 1) {
    alert(name + '' + number + '<h2>Поздравляем вы прошли тест на 100</h2>');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="text-center col-md-offset-3 col-md-7">Экзаменационный тест</h2>
    <div class="col-md-3 input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="txt" class="form-control" id="names" placeholder="Введите Имя">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-3 input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stud" placeholder="Введите Номер">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" id="question"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="ok();" value="Результат" style="margin:5% ">
```

При открытии страницы каждому вопросу присваивается `answer_0`(1 вопросу) и `value=0` первому ответу и тд.
хотел сделать через `if`, но он не определяет answer

> js.js:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: answer_0 is not defined
>   at ok (js.js:59)

Comment: Вам код ошибки явно говорит что answer_0 не определено. в функции ok да и в глобальном скоупе у вас нет переменной/функции с таким названием. То что вы назвали так html элементы не дает вам доступ к ним из js. Попробуйте найти их в DOM при помощи `findElementByName` а лучше сделайте `id =  answer_0 ` чтобы JS начал его понимать

Comment: Писали бы лучше код на одном языке и в одном стиле, читаемость кода из-за такого разнобоя жутко страдает

Comment: я работаю стажёром-программистом  и мой учитель дал задание сделать я решил html не забивать

Comment: @ТигранСаркисян Этот код он вам также дал, или вы его сами написали?

Comment: сам написал в начале он вообще не работал

Comment: @ТигранСаркисян надо писать отдельно, текст задания, исходный код, что вы сделали сами, какие ошибки у вас появились от того что вы написали. Без этого ваш вопрос не может рассматриваться здесь. Мы здесь не решаем задачи за кого-то, и если вы уже постите здесь ваше задание, то это означает что вы не смогли его выполнить самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В скрипте нужно достать значения из элементов, просто так он о них никаким волшебным образом узнать не может!

```js
var voprosy = [{
    "vopros": 'Столица Туркменистана?',
    "otvety": [
      'Ащхабад',
      'Мары',
      'Дашогуз',
    ],
    "otvet": [0]
  },
  {
    "vopros": 'Столица Италии?',
    "otvety": [
      'Милан',
      'Ватикан',
      'Рим',
    ],
    "otvet": [3]
  },
  {
    "vopros": 'Столица России?',
    "otvety": [
      'Москва',
      'Санкт-Петербург',
      'Тула',
    ],
    "otvet": [0]
  }
];

window.onload = draw();

function draw() {
  var questionBlock = '';
  var vopr = document.querySelector('.vopr');
  for (var i = 0; i < voprosy.length; i++) {
    var qwest = voprosy[i].vopros;
    questionBlock += '<div class="col-md-6 text-center"><h3>';
    questionBlock += qwest;
    questionBlock += '</h3>';

    for (var j = 0; j < voprosy[i].otvety.length; j++) {
      questionBlock += '<input type="radio" name ="answer_' + i + '" value="' + j + '" />' + voprosy[i].otvety[j] + '<br />';
    }

    questionBlock += '</div>';

  }
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questionBlock;
}

function ok() {
  const answer_0 = document.querySelector('input[name="answer_0"]:checked').value,
        answer_1 = document.querySelector('input[name="answer_1"]:checked').value,
        answer_2 = document.querySelector('input[name="answer_2"]:checked').value,
        name = document.querySelector('#names').value,
        number = document.querySelector('#stud').value;
  if (answer_0 == 0 && answer_1 == 2 && answer_2 == 0) {
    alert(name + '' + number + 'Поздравляем вы прошли тест на 100');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="text-center col-md-offset-3 col-md-7">Экзаменационный тест</h2>
    <div class="col-md-3 input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="txt" class="form-control" id="names" placeholder="Введите Имя">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-3 input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stud" placeholder="Введите Номер">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" id="question"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="ok();" value="Результат" style="margin:5% ">
```

Comment: все работает кроме - если не указать не один ответ страница дает ошибку на то что нету значений у answer_0 и тд (js.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at ok (js.js:55))

Comment: в if условие делал что если answerЫ = null 
 if(answer_0 == voprosy[0].otvet){
  
  count ++;
 }
 
 if(answer_1 == voprosy[1].otvet){
  count ++;
 }
 
 if(answer_2 == voprosy[2].otvet){
  count ++;
 }
 
 if(count == ''){
  alert('Ответте на вопросы');
 }
 
 if(count == 0){
  alert('Вы не прошли тест');
 }
 
 if(count == 1){
  alert('Вы ответили только на 1 вопрос');
 }
 
 if(count == 2){
  alert('Вы ответили только на 2 вопрос');
 }
 
 if(count == 3){
  alert('Вы ответили только на 3 вопрос');
 }